# Maximum value of angular acceleration

Tags: acceleration, angular-velocity

In a [video of Prof. Walter Lewin](https://youtu.be/MZ5eKUlO2fU?t=210), in which he is talking about the maximum value of angular acceleration, he says that it does not imply that the angular acceleration is zero if the angular velocity is zero and that when the object conducting some angular motion is stationary the angular acceleration is maximum for the object—or something like that; at least that's what I understood from it. Can anyone please give and explanation as to what he is trying the say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to SHM.  When an object performs SHM the displacement from the equilibrium is

$$x=A\sin (\omega t) $$

by differentiating, there are equations for velocity and acceleration

$$v=A\omega\cos (\omega t) $$

$$a= - A\omega^2\sin (\omega t) $$

from graphs of those functions it can be seen that at positions where $v$ is zero the acceleration is maximum. That's because  the zero velocity happens furthest from the equilibrium position, where the restoring force is largest.

The Professor on the video was talking about a similar thing for angular quantities.

Comment: Yes sir I guess you are right ,also he was explaining this for a simple pendulum thus its and example of SHM. At v=0 ,wt becomes pie/2 and putting pie/2 at "a" for wt , gives us the max value of "a" as sin(pie/2) is the max value of sin function. And to feel this thing as you said at extremes pointa in the pendulums the velocity is monetarily zero and the restoring force is max and thus acceleration at that point is max and decreases as the particles comes towards mean point of the pendulum.